# drf_yasg and amazon api gateway returns json instead of html ui

Tags: django-rest-framework, swagger, drf-yasg, aws-api-gateway

I have setup my python api service using djangorestframework and I am using drf_yasg for showing swagger docs for my api.

Here is glance of setup:

```
schema_view = get_schema_view(
   openapi.Info(
      title='My API',
      default_version='v1',
      description='rest service',
      terms_of_service='',
      contact=openapi.Contact(email='my@email'),
      license=openapi.License(name='BSD License'),
   ),
   public=False,
)

urlpatterns = [
    path('pyapi/weather/', include('apps.weather.urls')),


    re_path(r'^pyapi/swagger(?P<format>\.json|\.yaml)$', schema_view.without_ui(cache_timeout=0), name='schema-json'),
    re_path(r'^pyapi/swagger/$', schema_view.with_ui('swagger', cache_timeout=0), name='schema-swagger-ui'),
    re_path(r'^pyapi/redoc/$', schema_view.with_ui('redoc', cache_timeout=0), name='schema-redoc'),
]
```

Next I setup this api with amazon ec2 and stuff, and I am using Amazon API Gateway to access the api from containers.

[image: API Gateway setup]

Now the problem is when I try to access that using api gateway domain, it returns **swagger JSON** instead of HTML.
I tried several things like setting `Content-Type` mappings in method response and integration response but nothing works.

In my local machine it shows html as expected, so I am suspecting problem is in my gateway settings.

I highly appreciate if someone can help!

Comment: Hanen't used YASG, so just some general questions.  Is the required trailing '/' throwing it somehow, i don't see that in the api-gateway?  Maybe try locally with DEBUG=False in settings.py and see if the same thing happens?  You could manually request it from localhost:8000 using `httpie` and try to replicate it by adding/removing headers, maybe api-gateway is filtering something.

Comment: Thanks! I tried running locally using Debug=False, and it still works fine! Actually even from aws load balancer if I try to access , it works fine. Only when it come thru API Gateway, suddenly it changes response to json. I don't understand that mystery!

Answer (score 1):

Ok I solved mystery!
After tons of tries and looking here and there, I found there was problem in API Gateway **Request** header setting.

Actually drf-yasg also kind of weird let me tell you why.
After setting up urls as I shown in first image, if you try to access `http://localhost:8000/pyapi/swagger/` it shows UI perfectly.
At that time value of request header is `Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9`

Now same URL if you pass request header `"Accept: application/json"` then istead of showing html UI, it shows swagger JSON! wutt!!

That I found in Amazon API Gateways's **test** method's output. It was by default sending `"Accept: application/json"` and thats why I was always getting swagger.json in output. That was showstopper thing!
I changed it to `Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9` and now I could see UI perfectly!

I hope this will save time of many other people like me who are new to this kind of stuff!

Comment: Well solved.   I didn't realize it was the test function from the gateway that you were using, sorry.  I assumed that in prod mode it might disable the html UI basically.